# Is there a way to get the first result of a for loop?

Tags: python, loops

I was wondering if there is any way to save the first result of a for loop as a variable, and not the last. I wanted to get the first result of searching on youtube, following the code in https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl. The for loop is something like this,

```
for vid in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'yt-uix-tile-link'}):
    vids = 'https://www.youtube.com' + vid['href']
```

But I want the first result, not the last.

Comment: What do you mean by "the result of a for loop"?

Comment: plz explain more what u want

Comment: It would help to show an example that includes your desired outcome. Kind of sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: If you want the "first result", then why are you executing the loop at all?  Perform the operation that one time and continue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
test = 0
for i in range(5):
  if i == 0:
   test = i
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: I don't know the result, though.

Comment: Whats the array look like?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

so you want to get 1, the first element. You can do `lst_saved = lst[0]`

but if you want to use a loop and get the first element, you could use

```
for i in lst:
  lst_saved = i
  break
```

but that's... awful

Comment: since you can lst[0] there's no reason to use a loop, that's what I meant

Comment: `lst[0]` of course assumes it's a list and not some other iterable that can't be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you **just** want the first element, or are you trying to *complete the loop then access the first one*?

Either way, I'd avoid a loop, and doing something else.

For the former, you can just ignore the rest of the list do something like this since the "list[0]" syntax will just pick out the first item in the list:

```
what_you_want = 'https://www.youtube.com/' + soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'yt-uix-tile-link'})[0]['href']
```

Or otherwise, I'd recommend using list concatenation so that you're not overwriting the variable each time you loop. You can achieve the same thing multiple ways, but here's how I'd go:

```
# first get your list of links
list_of_things = ['https://www.youtube.com/' + vid['href'] for vid in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'yt-uix-tile-link'}]

# then pick out the first item in your list
what_you_want = list_of_things[0]
```